# Measurability of $\limsup$ over an uncountable index set

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, limsup-and-liminf

In the stochastic processes course I am taking, the following result was stated without proof.

Claim. $\quad$ *Suppose that $B_t$ is a standard brownian motion with respect to the filtration $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\geq 0}$, and let
$$
A_n = \left\{\limsup_{t \searrow 0 } \frac{B_t}{\sqrt{t}} > n \right\}.
$$
Then $A_n \in \mathcal{F}_0^+$, where $\mathcal{F}_0^+ = \bigcap_{t > 0} \mathcal{F}_t$.*

I can see that since $B_t$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$ are measurable with respect to $\mathcal{F}_t$ for all $t$. I also know that $\limsup: \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a measurable function, but I don't see how to prove it for $\limsup: \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. In fact I don't really even know how $\limsup$ is defined on an uncountable index set. Is anyone able to help me with a proof of this statement?

Comment: Don't think of $\limsup$ as a map. Instead try to write down how the limsup is defined (with $\epsilon$-$\delta$ stuff). If you are able to write it as countable unions and intersections of measurable sets, then you are fine.

Comment: By definition, $\limsup_{t\to 0^+} \frac{B_t}{\sqrt{t}}>n$ if and only if there exists a positive real sequence $t_1,t_2,\ldots$ such that $t_i \to 0$ and $\frac{B_{t_i}}{\sqrt{t_i}} > \sqrt{n}$ for all $i$. You can take that as the definition of that event. Now, assuming this, you can prove using the continuity of Brownian paths that there exists a sequence of *rationals* $t_i$ so that the same thing above holds. Basically you only need to focus on $\frac{B_{t}}{\sqrt{t}}$ when $t$ is rational.

Comment: Thanks guys I think I can see how to do it now.